# Regex for matching only legitimate tokens and discarding characters on the first indication of a bad token

Tags: python, regex

I have a regular expression like so:

```
(?x)
^(?:[^S]*)
(?:S
    (?:
        (?:(PING|PONG)E)                  # match and capture a token
        |
        (?!P).+                           # match and discard all that don't start with any prefix of the tokens
        |
        .+(?<!PING|PONG|PIN|PON|PI|PO|P)$ # match and discard all that don't end properly (if there's garbage at the end)
    )
)?
```

A demonstration of this regex is here: https://regex101.com/r/IGCnLE/4

I'm attempting to experiment with regex as a simple lexer. Basically there's a character stream with messages like `SPINGE` and `SPONGE`. But there could be other stuff in it. I use the above regex to do 2 things. One to find all the characters that should be discarded because they cannot result in an legitimate capture, and two to capture the first legitimate token that appears.

The above regex works for all cases except in these 2:

```
SPINGP
SPINGPINPINGPING
```

The above 2 are partially completely messages with no ending frame of `E`. But because they have some garbage after the `PING`, that means these are not legitimate tokens to capture. The entire string should be matched and discarded. But I can't figure it out.

Note that the discard operation is not in the regex itself, I make use of the match index in order to know how much of the character stream to discard.

The other test cases are on the website: https://regex101.com/r/IGCnLE/4 and copied down here:

```
S
SP
SPI
SPIN
SPING
SPONG
SPO
SPINGP
SPINGPINPINGPING
SPINGESPONGE
abcSPINGEabc
SPINGEabc
abcS
abcS   
Sabc...
SP   
SPINGG

S   
abc
SPONGe
SOP
SNIPO
SabcPINGE
SPINGabcE
SabcE
```

While I could do this without regex, since I came this far with writing it, I'd like to see how it could be done in regex.

Comment: Why not just match `SP[IO]NGE`?

Comment: @melpomene Because I still need to discard useless characters from my character stream. If it were that simple, then I wouldn't have asked this question.

Comment: I don't get it. What does the code that uses this regex look like?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai Sounds like you might want to build a FSM to match `SP[IO]NGE`, if the problem is that you want to feed it data incrementally.

Comment: @melpomene `lexical_analysis = re.search(protocol, client_input_buffer.decode('ascii'))` then `token = lexical_analysis.group(1)` then `client_input_buffer = client_input_buffer[lexical_analysis.span()[1]:]`. Whether the `token` is `None` or not is what prompts a token handling operation. The `span()` allows me to use the regex matching index to discard data. All code is in Python.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to split the input into lines first, then match each line against `SP[IO]NGE` and proceed accordingly?

Comment: There are no lines in this character stream. And even if there were, there's no guarantee of how long a line is.

Comment: Then I don't understand the input format at all. Sorry.